# un-installing a microwave that does not have any visible top cabinet attachment

Tags: microwave-oven, removal

I want to uninstall a Hotpoint model RVM1335 over-the-range microwave.  I thought I'd take it easy; so, I purchased installation and cart-away.  When the Home Depot delivered the replacement, they didn't know how to uninstall the old microwave; so now, the new one sits on my living room floor.

I found the installation instructions online for the existing oven. There is a paragraph on uninstalling it; but, they assume that the microwave was attached to both the back wall and the upper cabinet [like most.]

There are no [visible] screws or bolts either to the upper cabinet or to the cabinets on each side; only a hole for the power cord.  I "inherited" this in a home purchase; so, there's no one to ask.

Has anybody seen this before?

Comment: Could the screws been covered in the cabinet with say a sheet of plywood?

Comment: What's on the other side of the wall?

Comment: I haven't measured; but, the other side of the wall is either in a hallway or the master bath.

Comment: There is no plywood covering the bottom of the cabinet; it is a smooth surface.

Comment: It's time to post some good quality photos. You have several of us wracking our brains here.

Comment: I took a photo; but, haven't  yet figured how to upload them; I'm new to the site.  Anyway, I have egg on my face; I found the screws.  This puppy was mounted from the sides with two flush screws that were hidden by the cabinet shelves in each cabinet.  Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 5):

I know it's an old post, but I didn't see any removal instructions that worked for us anywhere (here or elsewhere).

I just removed Hotpoint microwave Model rvm1535bc. I tried to lean it (thinking there was a lip on a wall bracket holding it in place). That didn't work. As it turned out, the under-the-counter rvm 1535 in our house had a bracket that the microwave slid onto and off of. There were also four bolts coming down from the cabinet immediately above it. See photo. Hope that helps someone looking for an answer.

[image: bracket]

Answer (score 1):

I helped a friend solve this very mysterious situation recently. Although every range hood microwave I'd ever seen or installed had screws run through the shelf above, this one had screws from the side, through the faceframe of the adjacent cabinets. The screws were covered with plastic caps set flush with the rails, so they were nearly invisible. I don't recall whether it was 2 or 4 screws in total.

Also look underneath any hinge leaves in that location.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  The adjoining cabinets were the 2nd place I looked.  The next thing; I'll try to see if there's a false bottom in the upper cabinet.  I really grabbing at straws with this one.

Answer (score 0):

The microwave is most likely attached from the back to a wall bracket. The weight  of the unit is sometimes all that is needed to keep it in place. It will have to be fastened with at least 2 bolts along the front edge to prevent it from sagging. It may be difficult to notice them so with a flashlight open the cabinet doors and inspect the area just above the edge of the microwave. There should be bolts just a few inches from the front corners edge. Possibly a hex head bolt with a fender washer. They sometimes are colored black and are sized about 1/4 - 5/16 inches.

Sometimes you are able to see the threaded nut if the exhaust grille at the front top is removed. If there is no possible way to locate them as a final last act to remove the microwave use a reciprocating saw and cut the front bolts (but only with assistance).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I've got the grille off; and, I do not see any bolts from the inside.

Comment: With a flashlight, the space between the top of the unit and the cabinet bottom is empty but for the power cord slack.  The unit may be cantilevered from the wall with angle brackets; but, I don't see anything; so, that's a guess.  There is what looks like a cowling around three sides of the unit; it may be fastened to the wall, and the unit to it; but that too is a guess. I'm not inclined to keep removing screws; there's ceramic range top below  [the reason, I paid Home Depot to install it initially.] I'll see what Hotpoint says tomorrow..

Comment: The cowling may very well be screwed to the wall before the uWave was installed. The uWave may just be slid into position along two flanges that form the lower edges of the cowling. (It is also possible that the lower edge of the cowling fits into slide grooves/slots along the sides of the uWave). Try giving the uWave a good pull from the front to see if it starts to pull put. If so you'll have to feed the power cord down the hole as the unit pulls out.

Answer (score 0):

My last over the range oven had mounting screws behind the vent grille. Remove the 2 screws in the grill face above the door. Look in the opening for screws that attaches the top rear of the microwave to the wall mounted bracket. If I remember correctly I needed a long Phillips head screw driver to reach them.

Answer (score 0):

I found an installation guide for a Hotpoint RMV1635 [here](http://www.searspartsdirect.com/partsdirect/part-model/Hotpoint-Parts/Microwave-Parts/user-manuals/manual-downloads/Model-RVM1635BJ01/1811/0123370?modelNumber=RVM1635BJ01). With this model, you mount a horizontal bar across wall where the microwave will be installed against, aligned with the bottom of the microwave. You then hang the bottom rear of the microwave onto that bar:

[image: Setting rear of microwave on wall bar]

You then pivot the microwave up until it is horizontal, and then use three screws through the shelf above the microwave to hold it up:

[image: Installing top screws]

I'm betting the RMV1635 installs just like the RMV1335 you have. If so, then if you take a really careful look at the shelf just over the microwave, you'll either find those screws (they're extra-wide and extra-flat), or you'll find that the shelf removes to reveal a second under-shelf with the screws.

Comment: OP made it clear that there were no screws in that location.

Answer (score -1):

Using the make, model and serial numbers found on the existing microwave oven, search the internet for a copy of the old oven's installation manual.

Reverse the prescribed installation method to remove the microwave oven.

Comment: "Search Google" is discouraged as an answer on SE.

Comment: I did not suggest how to search the internet and especially did not suggest Google in particular.  I have used the process that I mentioned to solve the problem for myself so was using my own empirical anecdotal information to provide a viable answer to the question at hand.

Comment: Thanks, I have already gotten the installation manual through a search.  This one has got me stymied.